# My images are not being displayed when using GatsbyImage/getImage()

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I am attempting to create a gallery populating with .png's from src/projects/artwork directory.

I'm using GraphQl, Gatsby,gatsby-plugin-sharp,gatsby-plugin-sharp

**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `pages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `projects`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/projects/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `assets`,
        path: `${__dirname}/assets/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `artwork`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/projects/artwork/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `screenshots`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/screenshots/`,
      },
    },
    
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
      options: {
        defaults: {},
        failOnError: true,
        base64Width: 20,
        forceBase64Format: `png`,
        useMozJpeg: process.env.GATSBY_JPEG_ENCODER === `MOZJPEG`,
        stripMetadata: true,
        defaultQuality: 100,
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

**ArtworkPanel.js**

````
import React from 'react';
import {useStaticQuery,graphql} from "gatsby";
import {GatsbyImage,getImage} from "gatsby-plugin-image";
import "../scss/artworkpanel.scss";

export default function ArtworkPanel(){
    
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query artwork {
          artwork: allFile(filter: {base: {regex: "/^artwork-/"}}) {
            nodes {
              id
              childrenImageSharp {
                id
                gatsbyImageData(placeholder: DOMINANT_COLOR, formats: PNG)
              }
            }
          }
        }
    `)
    
    const artpieces = data.artwork.nodes;

    return (<>
        <div className="artworkPanel">
            {artpieces.map(artpiece =>{
                <div className="artwork" key={artpiece.id}>
                    <GatsbyImage className="artpiece"
                       image={getImage(
                          artpiece.childrenImageSharp.gatsbyImageData)
                    }/>
                </div>
            }
                
            )}
        </div>
    </>
    )
}```
````

Inside the ArtworkPanel component, when I log:

```
artpieces.forEach((piece)=>{
   console.log(piece)
})
//Object { id: "066a858d-0bdf-5195-b2c2-2a3e24d74f2a", childrenImageSharp: (1) […] }
​//Object { id: "e7208062-948f-5bc2-b635-93da713ec09e", childrenImageSharp: (1) […] }
```

There are *only* two images right now. Drilling even further, I get:

```
artpieces.forEach((piece)=>{
   console.log(piece.childrenImageSharp[0].gatsbyImageData)
})
//Object{layout:"constrained",backgroundColor:"#080808",images:{…},width:1920,height:1080}
//Object{layout:"constrained",backgroundColor:"#f8f8f8",images:{…},width:1123,height:794}
```

Here's where I'm stumped.  Why won't the images come up in the DOM?

```
return (<>
        <div className="artworkPanel">
            {artpieces.map(artpiece =>{
                <div className="artwork" key={artpiece.id}>
                    <GatsbyImage className="artpiece" image={getImage(artpiece.childrenImageSharp[0].gatsbyImageData)}/>
                </div>
            }
                
            )}
        </div>
    </>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`getImage` is a helper function (optional) that cleans up your code by pointing to the parent image node. In your case, you should do:

```
getImage(artpiece)
```

Or directly:

```
artpiece.childrenImageSharp.gatsbyImageData
```

Both should work.

Applied to your code:

```
<GatsbyImage className="artpiece" image={artpiece.childrenImageSharp[0].gatsbyImageData}/>
```

Note: accessing the `[0]` position may not be required. Test it in your scenario.

Comment: In which cases does the array occurs ? I found that getImage is not working when childrenImageSharp is an array.

Comment: Depending on the source and on the fetched node. `childImageSharp` stands for one image while `childrenImageSharp` is an array. If that's your case, follow the answer above where you access to a specific position `[0]` in this case otherwise it may not be needed